# How do I call a method from another class within a listbox?

Tags: c#, methods

In my listbox form I want to make it possible to call a method from a class in a different folder. Here is what I thought I was meant to do:

```
public void ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SharedClasses.Form.FormConsole newFormConsole = 
        new SharedClasses.Form.newFormConsole();
}
```

Comment: Replace "folder" with "namespace".

Comment: SharedClasses is my namespace I meant sorry. I get 'SharedClasses.Form.FormConsole ()' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type' in the error list

Comment: Are you a Java programmer? Folders do not dictate namespaces, unlike Java. A Namespace must be declared explicitly (though, by default, Visual Studio uses the folder structure as the namespace).

Comment: I rolled back your question, because the edit you made last was not in accordance with the Q&A purpose of this site. If that's not what you want, deleting it would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of the `FormConsole` class, which I'm guessing is probably not what you wanted to do.

What you probably want to do is have the form that contains your ListBox have a *reference* to an existing instance of `FormConsole`. Then you can call methods on that instance.

So, somewhere in the class that contains your ListBox:

```
private FormConsole _myForm;
```

You can set that in the constructor for your class, or provide a getter and setter:

```
public FormConsole MyForm
{
    get { return _myForm; }
    set { _myForm = value; }
}
// and/or...
public ListBoxForm(FormConsole myForm) 
{
    MyForm = myForm;
}
```

Then you can call (public) methods on myForm:

```
public void ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyForm.MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: I think you may have misinterpreted me, the listbox is in a class and the method I want to use is in another class in another folder.

Comment: @JackWebb: What do you mean "another folder"? If it's in the same project, you should be able to use it. If it's in another namespace, you should be able to add a `using` statement (or just use a fully qualified name) and use it. If it's in another project (within the same solution), you'll need to add it as a reference to your project. If it's not in the same solution, you can add a reference to a compiled dll.

Comment: Sorry I mean namespace, to me on the right I categorize it as a folder sorry. I added the using statement which fixed it but now I get "SharedClasses.Form.FormConsole ()' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'" what exactly does this mean and how would I go about fixing this. I am still using  SharedClasses.Form.FormConsole newFormConsole = 
        new SharedClasses.Form.newFormConsole(); if that makes a difference.

Comment: @JackWebb: You are using it like a class because you are using the `new` keyword. The `new` keyword instantiates a new instance of a type (or class). Drop the new, and if you method is static it should work. If it's not static, then you need a reference to an instance of that class and you are back with basically what I originally said.

Comment: Ah okay sorry, for some reason I thought I had to do it like a class which was confusing me. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest i think would be to copy the other application folder in the main folder of your current application and then using the classes from the other application folder with this code snippet:

```
using yourcurrentappname.otherappsfoldername;
```

and now you can easily access the methods of other app's classes here in the current app.